# How do I access the 2nd element with the same xpath in python in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

What I mean is that the website I'm using has 2 dropmenus named province with the exact same id, so how do I tell python which dropmenu in particular I wanna select. Of course this is assuming that the issue is that python always picks the first id it sees

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

   # There are two dropmenu with the same xpath. first time it works fine 
   # 2nd time it throws an error about element not interactable 

   Prov = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]'))
   Prov.select_by_index(2)
```

```
def Start():
    # once opened it will fill in the confirm your age
    Day = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bday_day"]'))
    Day.select_by_index(2)
    Month = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bday_month"]'))
    Month.select_by_index(4)
    Month = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bday_year"]'))
    Month.select_by_index(24)
    Prov = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]'))
    Prov.select_by_index(5)
    Button = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popup-subscribe"]/button')
    Button.click()

# have to go through select your birthday
Start()
# 2 seconds is enough for the website to load
time.sleep(2)
# this throws and error. 
Prov = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]'))
Prov.select_by_index(5)
```

Comment: use `find_elements_by_...` with char `s` in word `elements` to get all items

Comment: you shouldn't duplicate IDs - HTML should have on one object with `id` - and this is why there is `find_element_by_id` without char `s` in word `element` - to get first and the only element with some `ID` - but there is no `find_elements_by_id` with char `s` in word `elements` - to get more then one element with some `ID`

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has functions

- `find_element_by_...` without `s` in word `element` to get only first element
- `find_elements_by_...` with `s` in word `elements` to get all elements

Selenium doc: [4. Locating Elements¶](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

So you can get all elements as list (even if there is only one element in HTML)
(if there is no elements then you get empty list)

```
elements = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]')
```

and later slice it

```
first  = elements[0] 
second = elements[1] 

last   = elements[-1]

list_first_and_second = elements[:1]
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can also try to slice directly in xpath like
(it starts counting at one, not zero)

```
'//*[@id="province"][2]'
```

or maybe

```
'(//*[@id="province"])[2]'
```

but I never used it to confirm if it will work.

---

**BTW:**

All `ID` should have unique names - you shouldn't duplicate IDs.

If you check documentation [4. Locating Elements¶](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) then you see that there is `find_element_by_id` without char `s` in word `element` - to get first and the only element with some ID - but there is no `find_elements_by_id` with char `s` in word `elements` - to get more then one element with some ID.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code with example HTML in code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

html = '''
<select id="province">
<option value="value_A">A</options>
<option value="value_B">B</options>
</select>
<select id="province">
<option value="value_1">1</options>
<option value="value_2">2</options>
</select>
'''

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

all_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]')

first  = all_elements[0] 
second = all_elements[1] 

prov1 = Select(first)
prov2 = Select(second)

print('--- first ---')
for item in prov1.options:
    print('option:', item.text, item.get_attribute('value'))
for item in prov1.all_selected_options:
    print('selected:', item.text, item.get_attribute('value'))
    
print('--- second ---')
for item in prov2.options:
    print('option:', item.text, item.get_attribute('value'))
for item in prov2.all_selected_options:
    print('selected:', item.text, item.get_attribute('value'))
```

---

**EDIT:**

There are two `province`.

When you use `find_element` in `Start` then you get first `province` in popup - and you can fill it. When you click button then it closes this popup but it doesn't remove first `province` from HTML - it only hide it.

Later when you use `find_element` you get again first `province` in hidden popup - and this time it is not visible and it can't use it - and this gives error. You have to use second `province` like in this example.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

def Start():
    
    # once opened it will fill in the confirm your age
    Day = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bday_day"]'))
    Day.select_by_index(2)
    Month = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bday_month"]'))
    Month.select_by_index(4)
    Month = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bday_year"]'))
    Month.select_by_index(24)

    # it uses first `province`
    Prov = Select(web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]'))
    Prov.select_by_index(5)
    Button = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popup-subscribe"]/button')
    Button.click()

web = webdriver.Firefox()
web.get('https://www.tastyrewards.com/en-ca/contest/fritolaycontest/participate')

# have to go through select your birthday
Start()

# 2 seconds is enough for the website to load
time.sleep(2)

# `find_elements` with `s` - to get second `province`
all_province = web.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="province"]')
second_province = all_province[1]

Prov = Select(second_province)
Prov.select_by_index(5)
```

Comment: Hi I tried using your method and found that there's only 2 elements with the same id. I still get the same error of "element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated" Both drop boxes are clearly visible and I can click and select a province no problem. I also don't know how to use elements in a find_element... since it throws me a An invalid or illegal selector was specified when I put

Comment: ` Elements = web.find_elements_by_id("province")
  print(Elements)
  second = Elements[1]
  Prov = Select(web.find_element_by_id(second)) `

Comment: you didn't say that you have error `"element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"` - and this is totally different problem.  And as I said in answer there is NO `find_elemens_by_id` (with `s`) - because HTML assums that every ID has to be unique - and you have to use `find_elements_by_xpath` (with `s`) to get all elements. And later `Select(second)`, not `Select(web.find_element_by_id(second)) `

Comment: I added `Minimal working code with example HTML in code` which shows how to select boht elements. As for `element not interactable`: in question you should add URL for this page and show minimal working code which gives error - and then we could copy and run it to see problem and test ideas for solutions.

Comment: https://www.tastyrewards.com/en-ca/contest/fritolaycontest/participate this is the website I'm using, you have to go through the select birthday first before you can access anything. the select birthday also has  the //*[@id="province"] xpath. My code is pretty messy

Comment: you could add this in question - more people may see it and more people may help you.

Comment: I added code with explanation. After clicking button it hides popup window but it doesn't remove first `province` from HTML - so later you get again first `province` which is hidden and it can't be use - and this gives error. You have to use second element